# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n!} \frac{n^{n+1}}{e^n} = \infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Show that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n!} \frac{n^{n+1}}{e^n} = \infty$$

Wihout using stirlings aproximation to n!

I've tried to compare this to a divergent sequence but didnt work. Also, I dont see how to use L'Hospital or slmething like this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't like questions of the form "prove X without using Y" when using Y leads to an obvious and straightforward proof. Curious if there is some simple proof for this, since the expression is only about $n^{1/2}$.

Comment: Well, they are not made to be liked. My teacher asked to prove it without Stirling, so what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemmas:

- This one could easily be proven by induction: $\displaystyle \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{k} \right) = n+1$
- You can try to prove these inequalities yourself since it's not difficult: $\displaystyle \left (1+\frac{1}{k} \right )^k\leq e \leq \left (1+\frac{1}{k}  \right)^{k+{1 \over 2}}\\$ . We will only need the second inequality, but both are easily provable by taking the logarithm of both sides.

Now,

> - We first write $n^n/n!$ in a better way: $\displaystyle \frac{n^n}{n!}=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k} \right)^n \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\prod_{k=1}^{i}  \left(1+\frac{1}{k} \right)^{-1}=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k} \right)^n\cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}  \left(1+\frac{1}{i} \right)^{-(n-i)}=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}  \left(1+\frac{1}{i} \right)^{i}$
> - Then, a lower bound: $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}  \left(1+\frac{1}{i} \right)^{i} \geq \prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left (e^{1} \cdot  \left(1+\frac{1}{i}\right)^{-1/2} \right )=\frac{e^{n-1}}{\sqrt[2]{n}}$
> - Finally, $\displaystyle {n^n \over e^n n!}\geq n^{-1/2}e^{-1} \Rightarrow {n^{n+1} \over e^n n!}\geq {n^{1/2} \over e}$ and we are done.

Comment: How do you prove $1\le \left(k+\frac12\right)\ln\left(1+\frac1k\right)$ ?

Comment: @chubakueno : $x\mapsto\frac1x$ is convex, so $\frac1{\frac12(1+(1+\frac1k))}\le\frac1{(1/k)} \int_1^{1+1/k} \frac1x \,dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this observation could help as a start $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=  \frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}}{e}>1$$  with $$u_n =\frac{1}{n!} \frac{n^{n+1}}{e^n}$$

Comment: $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} >1$ doesn't imply $u_n \to \infty$. Any increasing convergent sequence satisfies that.

Comment: $$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \frac{n!(n+1)^{n+1}(n+1)}{(n+1)!n^{n+1}e} = \left(1+\frac1n \right)^{n+1} \frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: You should show that it is also unbounded to use this fact

Comment: @N.S. Thank you, I've edited. You are right!

Answer (score 0):

By Stirling, $\frac{1}{n!}\bigl(\frac{n}{e}\bigr)^{n-1} \simeq \frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi}n^{3/2}} \to 0$ if $n \to \infty$. Thus, 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!e^n} = \infty
$$

Answer (score -1):

$$ a_n = \frac{n^n}{n!\,e^n} < \frac{n^{n+1}}{n! \,\,e^n}$$
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)^{n+1} \, e^n \, n!}{e^{n+1} (n+1)! n^n} = (1 + \frac 1n)^n \to  e > 2 $$

$$ \exists\, n_0: \,\, \forall n > n_0 \,\, a_{n+1} > 2 a_n $$
$$  a_{n_0+p} > 2^p a_{n_0}\rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty \rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^{n+1}}{n!\,\, e^n} = \infty $$

Comment: $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \left( 1 + \frac1n \right)^n \cdot \frac1e$$

Comment: @Joel doesnt that shows that the sequence is decreasing, since $(1+1/n)^n$ is increasing? This is not possible

Comment: I am simply pointing out an algebraic mistake in simplifying the ratio. You can check it yourself if you like.

Comment: What it actually says is that $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{1}{e} \lim \left( 1 + \frac1n \right)^n = \frac{e}{e} = 1$.

Comment: Yes, I know. But this looks strange to me, since $(1+1/n)^n < e \Rightarrow a_{n+1}/a_n < 1$. How can this go to infinite? Your ratio is not right

Comment: Notice that @LambertoLamberti is working with a strictly smaller sequence than what was asked for by the OP. There is no claim that $a_n$ should go to infinity.

Comment: I Aam just saying that your ratio $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is not correct, it is $(1+1/n)^{n+1} 1/e$, as you wrote in another comment

Comment: The $a_n$ in Lamberto's answer is not the same as $u_n$ in Stefan's.

Comment: Oh, indeed. Sorry